# Whatever vs. However

Tags: word-choice

> React **whatever**/ **however** you want on my photo on Facebook.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the answer's grammatical accuracy can be checked by reconstructing the question to which it provides an answer to.

> React **however** you want on my photo on Facebook.

This can be assumed to be an answer to: **How should I react to your photo on Facebook?**
It's generally "*how you react*" and "*not what you react*". It is the way or manner you do something (which is to '*react*', in this case).